# How can I batch convert subfolders of images into single PDFs?

Tags: command-line, pdf, images, batch, conversion

I'm surprised I couldn't find an easy script for this online. I have a directory with lots of subdirectories, each filled with TIFFs. How can I batch convert subfolders of multiple images (TIFFs) into single PDFs each named after their parent folders? CLI solution and ability to set output directory preferred

ex. 
`dir > 1998 > Jan011998 > 1.tif 2.tif ... → Jan011998.pdf (or, ideally, 1998-01.pdf)`
 `dir > 1999 > 02231999 > 1.tif 2.tif ... → Feb231999.pdf (or 1999-02-23.pdf)`

Comment: irfanview can create the multi-page PDFs, but as far as I know it cannot be done from the command line. I suppose you could create a macro to do the job. AutoHotkey can do this, including sending the correct keystrokes into the application to drive it.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/81290/batch-convert-tiff-images-to-pdf?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Jasper: That's a start, but I'd need some sort of bash scripting or something to iterate through the bottom subdirectories (and I'm not sure how the batching would work either)

Comment: are you on win or linux or sth. else?

Comment: @Jasper: Mac, so UNIX is fine and I can run Windows through Parallels

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little script that should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=$(find . -type f -name "*.tiff" | xargs dirname |sort -u)

for d in $dirs; do
    #ls $d/*.tiff  # just debug info, should list all desired tiffs
    #echo $(cut -d/ -f3 <<<$d)  # debug info, should be desired output file name
    convert $d/*.tiff $(cut -d/ -f3 <<<$d).pdf

done
```

First, `find` is used to determine all directories that contain TIFF files. Then we use ImageMagick's `convert` to convert all TIFFs in each directory to a PDF file whose name is created from the directory. You can easily include a different output directory:

```
    convert $d/*.tiff somewhereElse/$(cut -d/ -f3 <<<$d).pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

The pdftk (PDF toolkit) program allows you to combine multiple PDF files into one big output pdf file.

```
$ pdftk in1.pdf in2.pdf in3.pdf cat output big_out.pdf
```